# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp \ p e^{ipx}e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts

In Lancaster & Blundell's QFT book they show that

\begin{equation}A:= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp \ p e^{ipx}e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}\end{equation}

returns a nonzero value for $x$, $t$ and $m$ beeing positive real numbers.

First the branch points at $p=\pm i  m$ are detected. Then the branch cuts and the contour are made as shown in the picture.

[image: Branch cuts and integration courve]

There is no pole inside of our integration courve, so the complete integral will return zero and therefore $-A$ must be equal to the rest of the contour integral.

Then they state, that with joran's lemma we see that the half-circle does not contribute to the integral. But i dont see it. For jordans lemma to work we first have to show that $p e^{-it \sqrt{p^2+m^2}}$ goes to zero as the radius of $p$ diverges on the upper half of the complex plane. But how do we show this?

Then for the remaining integral by substituting $p=iz$ they find 
\begin{equation}
A=\int_m ^\infty d(iz) \  ize^{-zx}\left( e^{t\sqrt{z^2-m^2}}-e^{-t\sqrt{z^2-m^2}}\right).
\end{equation}

My question is: Why?! Can somebody help me reproduce this in detail?

To prevent a wrong image: There are some arguments in the textbook, but i can't reproduce them, and i guess that simply copy & pasting them would hurt copyright.

Comment: Have you checked to see if enclosing both branch points keeps it single valued?

Comment: I have the same issue. Notably, I cannot see how they get the last exponential term via substitution of p=iz.