# How to evaluate integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx x e^{iax}e^{-ic\sqrt{(x^2 + b^2)}}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration

Like the title says, I am trying to evaluate

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \cdot x e^{iax}e^{-ic\sqrt{(x^2 + b^2)}}$

I'm not a mathematician by trade, but I ran across this integral in my research and am lost with how to evaluate it. $a,b,c$ are positive and real. We also assume $a$ > $c$.

From what I understand, the way to go is contour integration and you can make an argument that will allow you to use Jordan's lemma to simplify the expression (honestly, I'm unable to justify it). The square root introduces a branch cut on the imaginary axis from $x = ib$. The square root in the exponential is really confusing me.

I found a close question here asked a year ago, but so far no answers: [How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp \ p e^{ipx}e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033800/how-to-integrate-int-infty-inftydp-p-eipxe-it-sqrtp2m2)

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: I also see a related technique here on pages 14 and 15: http://higgs.physics.ucdavis.edu/QFT-I.pdf

Here the author is able to estimate the integral and show it is non-zero. Still doesn't help me because I don't understand stationary phase techniques, but maybe someone sees something I don't.

Comment: Why that integral should be convergent? As $x\to +\infty$, $\sqrt{x^2+b^2}$ gets closer and closer to $x$, but $e^{iax}e^{-cix}$ is not a Riemann or Lebesgue-integrable function over $\mathbb{R}^+$. This objection strikes the other question, too, and it is probably the reason for which you got no answers: that integrals are not converging.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You're right. I saw the same thing, but I figured that I would throw the statement into Mathematica anyway... no luck. It appears that (as we would expect) the antiderivative has no form that can be expressed in terms of the current special functions Mathematica has access to (which is a great amount). When I threw on the limits of $x$ Mathematica simply choked, which is understandable. While this is of course still not proof, it does further evidence your statement and explain why the OP is not getting an answer... $ax-c\sqrt{x^2+^2}$ does not converge on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Maybe the $x$ outside should be squared? If that's the case then have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: Hopefully you can see the problem I am roughly working on (other question too) from this page in Google Books: http://bit.ly/1OfwssU The authors claim it is convergent.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think I may agree with you. Simply plotting the integrand does not give me any indication that the integral will converge. Perhaps I (or the authors) missed something. Frustrating!